# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated while accessing IBM Watson in Windows 8

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-watson

I am trying to access the IBM Watson Personality Insights Java API with a code in Eclipse on Windows 8. But while running the code,

I am getting the following exception :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.execute(WatsonService.java:184)

I am not getting any proper solution to the problem particularly with respect to Windows. How can I solve that?

Edit :-
I am using the Oracle Java JDK 1.8 . I am also using Eclipse Mars.

Code Snippet :-

```
String myProfile = "Call me Ishmael. Some years ago-never mind how ";  
PersonalityInsights service = new PersonalityInsights();  
service.setUsernameAndPassword("<USERNAME>", "<PASSWORD>");  
Profile personalityProfile = service.getProfile(myProfile);  
System.out.println(personalityProfile);
```

The `<USERNAME>` and `<PASSWORD>` are the usernames and passwords for the Personality Insights API in Watson.

Comment: Please share some code snippets.

Comment: Which JRE vendor and version are you using?

Comment: I could get the code running .. And I did not do any edits. I am not sure how the exception was resolved.